# Python - Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

why I cannot do my project in my python console?

here's is what I'm doing...

C:\Users\DnetVaggos\Python\WebScraping\Scrapy\SCC>Scrapy shell https://spurverbr
eiterung.de/

### Note: It's because I'm using python 3.6.5?

**and I'm getting this:**

```
2018-05-31 01:12:15 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: scrapybo
t)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DnetVaggos\Miniconda3\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 5, in <mo
dule>
    sys.exit(scrapy.cmdline.execute()enter code here)
  File "C:\Users\DnetVaggos\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", lin
e 149, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "C:\Users\DnetVaggos\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", lin
e 252, in __init__
    log_scrapy_info(self.settings)
  File "C:\Users\DnetVaggos\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\log.py", l
ine 149, in log_scrapy_info
    for name, version in scrapy_components_versions()
  File "C:\Users\DnetVaggos\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\versions.p
y", line 35, in scrapy_components_versions
    ("pyOpenSSL", _get_openssl_version()),
  File "C:\Users\DnetVaggos\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\versions.p
y", line 43, in _get_openssl_version
    import OpenSSL
  File "C:\Users\DnetVaggos\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\__init__.py", l
ine 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "C:\Users\DnetVaggos\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", lin
e 16, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "C:\Users\DnetVaggos\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line
 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "C:\Users\DnetVaggos\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bin
dings\openssl\binding.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
ImportError: DLL load failed: Το λειτουργικό σύστημα δεν είναι δυνατό να εκτελέσ
ει %1.
```

Comment: The error explanation is this greek phrase - can you translate? `Το λειτουργικό σύστημα δεν είναι δυνατό να εκτελέσ
ει %1`

Comment: P.S Im new to python programming language, i want to use it for web scraping.

Comment: @DanielleM.it mean The operating system cannot run %1

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: does anyone know how to fix it please?

Answer (score 0):

You have not installed scrapy properly. I had the same problem, i would suggest to reinstall python using Anaconda, it's a package manager that helps you installing packages, modules ecc...
Anaconda : [Link to Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/)

Once you have downloaded it, install it and then run on your prompt this code :

```
conda install -c conda-forge scrapy
```

You can find the whole documentation here: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html

Try this and let me know if it solves your problem.